# How to give validation summary for specific models in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, model

Creating Form in MVC. trying to add validation summary in form.

but it shows validation for all fields.

How to show specific validation summary with asterisk sign?

**View**

```
 <div class="col-md-12 table-bordered" style="padding: 20px; margin:10px;">
    <div class="col-md-12">@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:10px;">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="width:95%;">
                @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.ItemName, new { style = "font-weight:bold;", @maxlength = "100" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.ItemName)
                <span class="text-danger"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.ItemName) </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="width:75%;">
                @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.ActiveProductGroup, new { style = "font-weight:bold;" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.ProductGroupID, new SelectList(ViewBag.ActiveProductGroup, "Value", "Text"), "--Select Value--", new { style = "Width:95%" })
                <span class="text-danger"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.ActiveProductGroup) </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:10px;">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div style="width:70%;">
                @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.SequenceNumber, new { style = "font-weight:bold;" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.SequenceNumber, new { style = "text-align:right", Value = "", @maxlength = "3" })
                <span class="text-danger"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.SequenceNumber) </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div style="width:50%;">
                @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.UnitPrice, new { style = "font-weight:bold;" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.UnitPrice, new { style = "text-align:right", Value = "", @maxlength = "5" })
                <span class="text-danger"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.UnitPrice) </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div style="width:50%;">
                @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Quantity, new { style = "font-weight:bold;" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Quantity, new { style = "text-align:right", Value = "", @maxlength = "5" })
                <span class="text-danger"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Quantity) </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div style="width:80%;">
                @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.EstimatedDeliveryDays, new { style = "font-weight:bold;" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.EstimatedDeliveryDays, new { style = "text-align:right", Value = "", @maxlength = "2" })
                <span class="text-danger"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.EstimatedDeliveryDays) </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

> Models:-
>   [image]

- Want validation summary only for Item Name, Quantity, unit Price and
  product Group dropdown
- Is it possible to get validation summary of specific models?

Comment: Are you only validating these fields: `Item Name`, `Quantity`, `unit Price` and `product Group`? Can you also show us your model class.

Comment: Your form only has 6 form controls which means your view model should only contain 6 properties (do not use data models in a view)

Comment: Use HTML helpers with same amount of viewmodel properties you want to submit by the form, avoid using data model directly bound to view page.

Comment: Yes @Oluwafemi Check again. Added models screenshot

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I m using dropdown list of other tables for inserting values in this table

Comment: @StephenMuecke Using selectlist models. Didnt added in question

Comment: @RookieCoder. What dos that have to do with anything. Just remove all those properties not used in the view from your view model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per you view your viewmodel should only contain properties that are present in view. ex.ItemName,Product group image, sequence no. etc.
Create another viewmodel that contain only these properties and use it in your view.

However some of the properties that you've used like int32 etc. are always going to be validated by default. if you want to change that behavior make nullable properties for them.

Comment: Removing all the validation attributes solves nothing - OP has numerous properties that are `long`, `int32` etc which are always required (they cannot be `null`)

Comment: Yes, if he has something like that it is always being validated. but if it is not required he has to make it nullable.

Comment: but first he should remove all unnecessary properties from his viewmodel and make validations as per his requirement.

Comment: Exactly (so delete the first paragraph of your answer - its wrong)

Comment: @JaiminDave Yes it is because of int32 values.